# String recursive definition corner case

Tags: computer-science, recursion, regular-language

I need your assistance with a corner case of this problem:

Find a recursive definition for the strings of odd length that start with "a" and end with "b" over the alphabet $\Sigma$={a,b}.

I've already tried the following, but I can't get the string "aaaab", "aaaaaab, etc.:

Base case: aab,abb $\in$ L

Recursive step: If u$\in$L, then uab,ubb $\in$L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "recursive step" is not right, for a few reasons. You want to say that if $u$ is *any string* of odd length* then $aub\in L$, **not** just for strings $u\in L$. Try this grammar:
$$\begin{align}
S &\to aOb \\
O &\to COC \mid C \\
C &\to a \mid b
\end{align}$$

$C\stackrel{*}\Longrightarrow$ the symbols of $\Sigma$, and $O\stackrel{*}\Longrightarrow$ *all* odd length strings in $\Sigma^*$. Finally, $S\stackrel{*}\Longrightarrow aub$ for every odd-length $u$ string in $\Sigma^*$.

Comment: Thank you very much! That cleared things up.

Comment: You're welcome.